# How git makes branching not to be feared?

Tags: git, version-control, tfs

I'm a beginner in the Git world, previously working solely on centralized version control mechanism, namely TFS (tfvc) from microsoft. I already read couple tutorials, editorials, questions/answers on stackoverflow as well as created couple git repositories in which I work, but nothing fancy so far.

I'm curious as to why so often I run into statement like "why I feared branching before, but not anymore with git", or something to that sort? I'm not questioning that statement, I'm just looking for the reason as to why it is so.

From the editorials I've read, and how I understand git architecture so far, I do understand how branching is easy, and how lightweight it is (branches are simply pointers to commits), but still there is nothing magical about avoiding merge conflicts etc. The scheme of how the conflicts arise is the same, so why me, a beginner in git world, should not fear of doing many branches, switching between them, commiting, merging etc?

Thus far I work in a small team, so we have 1/2 people per project, so there are virtually no merge conflicts (no suprise there), but say you have a team of 50 engineers, who all are working on various parts of the application, and I just cannot help but think, that it's simply a nightmare every once in a while for them, when all those commits start to intersect one another.

Having a company convention, like same IDE's, same whitespacing schemes etc, is all fine and good, but it applies to any version control mechanism, doesn't it? So to finish my small remark, and repeat the main question:

"Why I should not worry about working on branches in git vs other version control mechanisms"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends...

if you have 50 people merging back to same branch then yes! You might have merge collisions and hell with `git`, with `svn`, with any tool (`git merge` is a little more sophisticated but it would not solve it!)

If you locally branch and merge as a "standalone" developer you will have nothing to fear.

Bottom line, the term has been abused.  `branching` and `merging` is a theoretical concept and you are perfectly right, it does not matter which tool you use, branching and merging are still the same abstract concept and should be feared and unfeared - the same with any tool!

The change which `git` brings is mainly that it allows for quick branching and merging,  locally or by distributed developers, but again if you have 50 people merging same code base - fear it - many merge problems will indeed occur `git` does not solve it (will have many screams here by git advocates :) ).

The issue here is ofcourse we have too many people working on same codebase and this does not relate to any source control tool but to teams structure and whether to use micro services or the monolyth design.

Comment: Thanks Tomer. Not completely answers my questions, but it's the best answer from the given ones, and since the topic is closed I will mark this as answered. The lightweight part was easy to figure out about git, but still the gist of it avoids me. I cannot find an answer, as to what makes git so special, when you have teams of dozens of developers working on the same project, and how to avoid the conflicts, that would seem to me, would be anavoidable and unbearable.

Answer (score 0):

I myself have worked with Git, SVN and Mercurial for the past 4 years. I find branching, merging, and switching between branches so much easier to do with Git. That and I feel that it's easier to fix conflicts. For SVN and Mercurial, I'm sure there are users out there that feel the same that those version control mechanisms are easy to work with, but I'd say 70-80% of the people I've worked with have been on the side of Git.

Answer (score 0):

Your right, there is nothing to fear about branching in Git. It is one of the great strengths of Git. Often, people fear it because they where never exposed to the idea of distributed version control, so the very concept of a branch can be scary, especial when you don't yet know about all of the tools that make them easy to manage and keep track of.

As far as managing a team with Git, this requires a protocol in order to not be maddeningly hard. This is a good strategy for using Git. This strategy lets everyone know where they are and what they should be working on.

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score 0):

You can merge easily changes that multiple developer have done in *different* parts of the same big text file. Who tried to put together changes done by different people on the same MS Word .doc document would recognize it is a *very* great feature.

Nothing can help, however, if incompatible changes are made in *the same part* of the document by different developers. Conflicts must be resolved manually for this case. However assuming your 50 developers are not working all on the same single feature, successful automated merges are frequent enough to make branch based development reasonable.